# Assembly - jmp and cmp result in infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86

Here is my code:

```assembly
%include "io.inc"

section .data
var DB 0
var2 DB 0

section .text
global CMAIN

print:
    PRINT_DEC 1, var
    inc BYTE [var]
    mov eax, [var]
    ret

forLoop:
    call print
    cmp eax, [var2]
    jle forLoop
    ret

CMAIN:
    GET_DEC 1, var2
    call forLoop
    ret
```

*This uses Simple-ASM's default library.*

When given with the input `5` (which is then placed into `var2`), I expect an output of:

```
012345
```

However, when given the input `5`, I get this instead:

```
01234567891011...127128-127-126...-10123...
```

It appears that the `cmp` and `jle` don't work properly when checking the two numbers, and `forLoop` never stops calling itself, which results in `var` being continuously `inc`ed.

When I placed a `PRINT_DEC 1, var2` after the `GET_DEC` statement, like so:

```
CMAIN:
    GET_DEC 1, var2
    PRINT_DEC 1, var2
    call forLoop
    ret
```

And comment out the other `PRINT_DEC` line, there's no output at all.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `PRINT_DEC` is presumably a macro defined by the Simple-ASM library, but since I don't know what Simple-ASM is and don't have it installed, I can't tell what the macro is, either. Can you locate and post the code for the macro? Also, what does `print` return? Unless the macro is implicitly adjusting `var2`, the code probably isn't going to do what you want, because `var2` will always be 0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax, but shouldn't `mov eax, [var]` be `mov eax, BYTE [var]` (and `cmp eax, [var2]` be `cmp eax, BYTE [var2]`)? Or maybe `al` instead of `eax`?

Comment: @CodyGray [here](https://github.com/Dman95/SASM/blob/ca35a1fdc0f7b6b28b8bcb2dd8773c85e48cb4d7/Windows/include/io.inc) it is.

Comment: @melpomene Well, that fixes the problem (changing `eax` to `al`). Thanks!

Comment: Very strange that @melpomene's suggestion fixed the problem (although it was correct). What you had originally *should not have assembled*. You should have gotten a fatal "operand mismatch error" or similar. What assembler are you using? It clearly has a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray Why shouldn't it have assembled originally?

Comment: Operand size mismatch. `var` is an 8-bit byte, `eax` is a 32-bit register. There is no encoding for `mov r32, m8`.

Comment: The problem was fixed by changing `eax` to `al`, if that helps. Can you post the solution, @melpomene?

Comment: @CodyGray `var` is a label, which becomes a memory address. `mov eax, [var]` is fine (it's a 32-bit move). My `BYTE` suggestion would make it invalid, yes.

Comment: It's in brackets, @mel. That means it's loading the *value* at that address, not the address itself. It's an 8-bit value (declared with `DB`, so it's a `BYTE`), which would be invalid. Unless maybe the assembler is doing some weird mind-reading tricks. MASM is sometimes known for this.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, and it's loading a 4-byte value from that address. There is no such thing as an "8-bit value"; the computer sees that we're `mov`ing into a 32-bit register so it copies 4 bytes from whatever address. Addresses are untyped. (`DB` isn't a declaration; it's a pseudo-instruction to emit a specific byte at the current address.)

Comment: Hmm. Every Intel-syntax assembler I've ever seen *is* strongly typed in this regard, and `DB` will be treated as a declaration of a BYTE-sized variable. Still not sure which assembler is being used here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    mov eax, [var]
```

`eax` is a 32-bit register, so this instruction copies 4 bytes from the label `var` into `eax`. Similarly,

```
    cmp eax, [var2]
```

compares `eax` with the 4 bytes at `var2`. This is a problem because `var` and `var2` only store 1 byte each.

Fix:

```
    mov al, [var]
```

and

```
    cmp al, [var2]
```

respectively. `al` is an 8-bit register (it's the lowest byte of `eax`), so this way we properly copy/compare 1-byte quantities.